# Google Maps com erro de file_get_contents. O que pode ser?

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-maps

Estou implementando o Google Maps em um site imobiliário e estou com um problema a resolver: a requisição dá erro de `file_get_contents($url)` ...

Logo no meio do código tem o resultado da variável `$url` que se eu copiar e colar na barra de endereço do browser, ele retorna o perfeito arquivo contendo todos os dados daquele imóvel com o endereço apresentado mas o **file_get_contents** não consegue executar a mesma tarefa.

Alguém sabe porque? Anexo também a **url** que retona o **[erro](http://imo.axitech.com.br/imovel?cod_consulta=2261)**.

**Código:**

```
<?php

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // CONSULTA GOOGLE MAPS
        $key = "AIzaSyCfYKBdv9RFbsHaRuUu7Pf5Ft8CrQ0wHQo";
        $address = 
            urlencode(
                $linha['ENDERECO_TIPO'].' '.
                $linha['ENDERECO'].', '.
                $linha['NUMERO'].' - Bairro '.
                $linha['BAIRRO'].' - '.
                $linha['CIDADE'].', '.
                $linha['UF'].', 
                Brasil'
        );

        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".
                $linha['ENDERECO_TIPO'].' '.
                $linha['ENDERECO'].', '.
                $linha['NUMERO'].' - Bairro '.
                $linha['BAIRRO'].' - '.
                $linha['CIDADE'].', '.
                $linha['UF'].', 
                Brasil'     
        ."&sensor=false";

        echo "<strong><em>" .$url. "</em></strong><br /><br />";

        # Este é o resultado da variável $url
        /* http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=RUA FELICISSIMO DE AZEVEDO, 1 - Bairro HIGIENOPOLIS - PORTO ALEGRE, RS, Brasil&sensor=false */

        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        $data['latitude']   = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $data['longitude']  = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

?>
```

Pedaço do erro: *failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in ...*

Se colocar este código depois da primeira `$response` e der `echo` aparece exatamente nada: `echo "<br /><br />Resposta: " .$response;` ... ou seja, o **file_get_contents** ou não está indo ou não está voltando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue uma versão com cURL:

```
<?php

    $key = "AIzaSyCfYKBdv9RFbsHaRuUu7Pf5Ft8CrQ0wHQo";
    $address = 
        urlencode(
            $linha['ENDERECO_TIPO'].' '.
            $linha['ENDERECO'].', '.
            $linha['NUMERO'].', Bairro '.
            $linha['BAIRRO'].' - '.
            $linha['CIDADE'].', '.
            $linha['UF'].', Brasil'
    );

    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode( $response, true );

    $data['latitude']   = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $data['longitude']  = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    echo 'Lat:'.$data['latitude'].' - Lon:'.$data['longitude'];
?>
```

> Notar que `$key` não está sendo utilizado neste exemplo.

Comment: Estou recebendo os dados **$data['latitude']** e **$data['longitude']** depois de ter feito a modificação. Obrigado pela ajuda. O mapa recebe as coordenadas mas não renderiza. Sabe o que pode ser? http://puu.sh/bU6Iy/43627088d0.png

Comment: Só de olhar o print assim não dá pra dizer. Tente resolver aí, mas se não conseguir, abra uma pergunta separada para tratar desta outra parte, e cole o código como texto, e não printscreen. Mas tente resolver antes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seu *server* esteja com o `file_get_contents` bloqueado. Existem duas configurações de segurança no `php.ini` que bloqueiam o uso do `file_get_contents`.

Elas são:

`allow_url_fopen` e `allow_url_include`

Verifique se elas estão desativadas usando o seguinte trecho no seu código:

```
<?php
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_include'));
?>
```

Se o resultado for `false`, precisa habilitar essas configurações :

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);
ini_set('allow_url_include', true);
```