# Erro 400 Bad Request na API de calculo de distancia do Google

Tags: php, google-maps

Esse é o Erro que esta acontecendo na hora de Enviar as Requisições pela url:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Av Padres Olivetanos|Brasil&destinations=AmadorBuenoDaVeiga|Brasil&mode=car&language=pt-BR): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste_xml\index.php on line 9

Warning: file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Rua Francisco Amaral|Brasil&destinations=AmadorBuenoDaVeiga|Brasil&mode=car&language=pt-BR): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste_xml\index.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste_xml\index.php on line 17
```

O erro acontece só quando coloco as requisições em loop

***Esse é o codigo***

```
$dados = array('Av Padres Olivetanos', 'Rua Francisco Amaral', '');


foreach ($dados as $rua) {
    //Faz a requisicao do arquivo xml   
    $url = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$rua."|Brasil&destinations=AmadorBuenoDaVeiga|Brasil&mode=car&language=pt-BR");
    $jsonObj = json_decode($url, true);
    print_r($jsonObj);


}

//Percorre o arquivo xml
foreach($jsonObj['rows'] as $distance) {
    echo 'A distancia para voce é de : ' . $distance['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
}
```

A ideia é que dentro do foreach ele calcule a distancia de mais de um lugar.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [Google Maps com erro de file_get_contents. O que pode ser?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34414/70)

Comment: William, edita tua questão e inclui o código que está gerando estas advertências, para que entendamos o contexto e possamos te auxiliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que codificar os dados passados pra querystring, pra isto use `urlencode` ou `rawurlencode` assim:

```
foreach ($dados as $rua) {
    //Faz a requisicao do arquivo xml

    $rua = rawurlencode($rua);

    $url = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$rua."|Brasil&destinations=AmadorBuenoDaVeiga|Brasil&mode=car&language=pt-BR");
    $jsonObj = json_decode($url, true);
    print_r($jsonObj);


}
```

Você também pode usar o `http_build_query` assim:

```
$data = array(
          'destinations' => 'AmadorBuenoDaVeiga|Brasil',
          'mode'         => 'car',
          'language'     => 'pt-BR',
        );

$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?';

foreach ($dados as $rua) {
    $data['origins'] = $rua. '|Brasil';

    $querystring = http_build_query($data);

    $url = file_get_contents($url . $querystring);

    $jsonObj = json_decode($url, true);

    print_r($jsonObj);
}
```

Documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme funcionou !